# smart way briefer code

Tags: jquery, function

may someone give me a smarter way to do the following code?
I know toggle could enter here.
And it must be possible somehow to integrate the if statements at the end in the first part.
Thanks for help!

```
function arrowShow( begin_end ) {       
    var begin = ( begin_end == 1  ) ? 0 :  10;
    var end   = ( begin_end == 17 ) ? 0 : -10;

    $("#element_1").css( { top: begin } );
    $("#element_2").css( { top: end } );

    if ( begin_end == 1  ) {
        $("#element_3").css( { display: 'none' } ); 
    } else {
        $("#element_3").css( { display: '' } ); 
    }

    if ( begin_end == 17  ) {
        $("#element_4").css( { display: 'none' } ); 
    } else {
        $("#element_4").css( { display: '' } ); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
function arrowShow( begin_end ) {       
    var elem1 = ( begin_end == 1  ) ? 0 :  10;
    var elem2 = ( begin_end == 17 ) ? 0 : -10;
    var elem3 = ( begin_end == 1  ) ? 'none' : '';
    var elem4 = ( begin_end == 17 ) ? 'none' : '';

    $("#element_1").css( { top: elem1 } );
    $("#element_2").css( { top: elem2 } );
    $("#element_3").css( { display: elem3 } );
    $("#element_4").css( { display: elem4 } ); 
}
```